# How to debug source code of NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, visual-studio-debugging

We use a Nuget-Package in our projects that contains code written by ourself. If we find a bug or the need for a new feature we currently change the content of the nuget-package, build it and publish a new package.

But we are lacking the possibility to directly go into the implementation of our package from within the calling project to debug the code in a real-world-environment because the reference is to a nuget-package and not the project-file of that package.

Removing the NuGet-Package and adding a reference directly to a folder containing the source instead is NOT an option for us.

Is there any way to hint VisualStudio that the source for the Package "Just.Some.Library.nuget" is in a specific directory or csproj on my harddrive so we can debug from within the parent project?

Comment: Publish the package with symbols

Comment: activate [source link](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#using-sourcelink) so that the PDBs include information where the debugger finds the source code

Comment: Sadly this is .net framework and source link only works with core